# DutchWorkz MSI build VS Installers addon not able to see the VS2019

Tags: windows-installer, azure-pipelines, devenv

I am getting a weird issue where there is `VS2019` installed on the build server but [DutchWorkz
MSI Addon](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dutchworkz.DisplayAllVariables&ssr=false#overview) only "sees" VS2013, VS2015 and VS2017,
[image]

None of which is able to build MSI project due to various reasons like expired licenses and devenv.com not being there...

[image]

Is there a way maybe instead of using magic `VS2013` VS instance name to pass disk location of where the devenv.com for VS2019 is or some other workaround, or a way how to make VS2019 appear in the list.
Or debug this further on why is it not there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> DutchWorkz MSI build VS Installers addon not able to see the VS2019

AFAIK, neither [DutchWorkz
MSI Addon](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dutchworkz.DisplayAllVariables&ssr=false#overview) (old version `1.1.7`) nor [Build VS Installer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dutchworkz.BuildInstaller) (New version   `1.2.4`) support VS2019.

That is the reason why you not able to see the VS2019 in the drop-down list.

Besides, both extensions are now unpublished from Marketplace.

To build the MSI Setup Projects, you could use the command line task to invoke the `devenv.com`：

Steps:

1. Add a `Command line` task
2. Add there following line: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\devenv.com" MyProjectDir\MySolution.sln /Rebuild Release`

Note: please note to use `devenv.com` (not `devenv.exe`).